# Loop for... non-sequential numbers

Tags: javascript

Currently I have this code that generates 32 buttons on a page.

```
var $bs =   $("#pages");
pages.forEach(function (page) {
    var $page = $("<div class='page'><h1 class='page-title'>Page "+page+"</h1></div>");

    for (var bank = 1; bank <= 32; bank++) {

        var $pageBank = $("<div class='page-bank-content' id='bank_"+page+"_"+bank+"'><canvas class='canvases' width=72 height=72 id='c"+page+"_"+bank+"'></canvas></div>");

        $page.append($pageBank);

    }
```

There are some instances where I want to only generate specific buttons. However, I'd like the +bank+ values to skip some numbers (ex: 1,2,3,4,9,10,11). Is there a way to do this using the above format? I tried using arrays but couldn't figure how to pass the specific number values I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could exclude some numbers with a check with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and an array.

```
var $bs = $("#pages"),
    exclude = [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11];

pages.forEach(function(page) {
    var $page = $("<div class='page'><h1 class='page-title'>Page " + page + "</h1></div>");
    for (var bank = 1; bank <= 32; bank++) {
        if (exclude.includes(bank)) continue;
        var $pageBank = $("<div class='page-bank-content' id='bank_" + page + "_" + bank + "'><canvas class='canvases' width=72 height=72 id='c" + page + "_" + bank + "'></canvas></div>");
        $page.append($pageBank);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you have `includes`, you  presumably have `let` as well.  if not, the `var` statements are in the wrong place inside the  for each call back